# c++ optional_t type tag (n3527)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

[n3527](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3527.html) proposes to add `std::optional<T>` to c++. As part of it, it defines `nullopt_t` type tag.

gcc's (4.9) libstdc++ defines `optional_t` as follows:

```
struct nullopt_t
{
    enum class _Construct { _Token };
    explicit constexpr nullopt_t(_Construct) { }
};
constexpr nullopt_t nullopt { nullopt_t::_Construct::_Token };
```

clang's (3.6) libc++ defines it as:

```
struct nullopt_t
{
    explicit constexpr nullopt_t(int) noexcept {}
};
constexpr nullopt_t nullopt{0};
```

My question is: why is it done that way, which is (seemly) overcomplicated?

In other words, why can't it be defined as follows:

```
struct nullopt_t { };
constexpr nullopt_t nullopt { };
```

This is how, for example, `std::defer_lock_t` and others are defined in the standard library.

Comment: It means there is no legal way to construct your own `nullopt_t`?  Sort of like `nullptr_t`?

Comment: Possibly related: [experimental::optional nullopt_t constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332078/)

Comment: @kakkoko, you put me on the right track! it has to do with the `op = {}` syntax. It basically makes `nullopt_t` non-`DefaultConstructible` in order to avoid ambiguity

Comment: `nullopt_t` has to only be constructible with `nullopt` expression. Ideally, this unique constructor has to be private with `friend` access for `nullopt`, but thus definitions of `nullopt_t` and `nullopt` depend on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself here, but credit goes to kakkoko for putting me on the right track.

The related question links to a newer revision [n3793](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html), which expounds on the extra complexity of `nullopt_t` in [The op = {} syntax](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html#rationale.reset_syntax) paragraph.

In a nutshell, the `nullopt_t` is declared that way to make it non-`DefaultConstructible` in order to avoid ambiguity of the `op = {}` syntax. You can read the aforelinked paragraph for further details.