# I am confused about a constexpr function?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

In C++ Primer, Fifth Edition, §6.5.2:

> A `constexpr` function is defined like any other function but must meet certain restrictions: **The return type and the type of each parameter in must be a literal type** (§2.4.4, p. 66), and the function body must contain exactly one return statement

but another sentence in this chapter (page 239):

> A constexpr function is permitted to **return a value that is not a constant**
>
> ```
> // scale(arg) is a constant expression if arg is a constant expression
> constexpr size_t scale(size_t cnt) { return new_sz() * cnt; }
> ```

Is it a contradictory summary? I am confused about it.
The return type of `scale` is literal type?
update:
what's the difference between literal type and constant ?

Comment: "Literal Type" doesn't necessarily mean integer constant, like `5`. The standard defines what a literal type is, but I can't be bothered to look it up right now. Here's [cppreference's page on it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType).

Comment: What do you think is contradictory? The types must be literal (such as `size_t`), and the values don't have to be constant. Presumably, §2.4.4, p. 66 describes literal types - it doesn't mean "constant", if that's what you thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not contradictory. As well as mandating that the return type must be of "literal type", the draft standard states that a call to a `constexpr` function does not have to appear in a constant expression. From the C++11 draft standard:

> §7.1.5/7 A call to a `constexpr` function produces the same result as
>   a call to a equivalent non-`constexpr`  function in all respects
>   except that a call to a `constexpr` function can appear in a constant
>   expression.

Answer (score 8):

First of all what I believe the author meant was that a constexpr function does not have to result in a [constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression), which is an expression that *can* be evaluated at compile time.

A constexpr function will only yield a *constant expression* if the arguments to the function are also *constant expressions* and the comment right after says exactly that:

```
// scale(arg) is a constant expression if arg is a constant expression
```

and the examples that follow right after also demonstrate this behavior:

```
int arr[scale(2)]; // ok: scale(2) is a constant expression
int i = 2; // i is not a constant expression
int a2[scale(i)]; // error: scale(i) is not a constant expression
```

In C++(*as opposed to C99*) as array size must be a *constant expression* and so the last case is an error since the argument to `scale` is not a constant expression.

This is different concept from the return type of the function, which must be a [literal type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LiteralType) which is any of the following:

- void(since c++14) (so that constexpr functions can return void)
- scalar type which includes Arithmetic types, enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to member types, std::nullptr_-
  t, and cv-qualified versions of these types)
- reference type
- an array of literal type
- class type that has all of the following properties:

  - has a trivial destructor,
  - is either

    - an aggregate type
    - a type with at least one constexpr (possibly template)    constructor that is not a copy or move constructor
  - all non-static data members and base classes are of non-volatile literal types.

Answer (score 1):

constexpr does nothing but tells the compiler that the value is there in compile time, so you can use it as template argument (for example)

```
int a1 = 5;
std::array<int, a1> arr1; // error, a is variable

const int a2 = 5;
std::array<int, a2> arr2; // OK

int f1() { return 3; }
std::array<int, f1()> arr3; // error, compiler doesn't know it is const 3

constexpr int f2() { return 3; }
std::array<int, f2()> arr4; // OK
```

Later you also can:

```
constexpr int f3() { return f1() + 1; } // error, f1 is not constexpr

constexpr int f4() { return f2() + 1; } // OK
std::array<int, f4()> arr5; // OK
```

Now about literal types limitation: the function arguments and result types should be literal types ([Need clarification on definition of literal type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581443/need-clarification-on-definition-of-literal-type)), the very same limitation as template arguments apply (known in compile types).

```
constexpr std::string f5() { return "hello"; } // error, 
                   // std::string is not literal type

constexpr const std::string& f6() { 
  static const std::string s = "hello";
  return s;
}

template<const std::string& s> SomeClass { ... };
SomeClass<f6()> someObject;
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that's asked. It may be somewhat relevant to the question title, but you should really read the full question.

Comment: sorry, will be more carefull next time